# При вводе символа и проверки на него if возвращает false

Tags: java

Я хочу чтобы при вводе определенного символа *(в данном случае "a")* выполнялось определенная последовательность команд, но при использовании if оказывается что (a != "a"). Я пытался найти что-нибудь в Интернете, но ничего не вышло. Может кто знает как исправить и из-за чего это? *Я даже на телефоне пытался этот же код запустить, но все равно выдает* **false**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Symbol: ");
            String symbol = scan.next();
            if (symbol == "a") {System.out.println("true");}
            else {System.out.println("false");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"a".equals(symbol)
```

PS: А возвращать может только `return`.

Comment: Минус за простой ответ на _явный_ дубликат.

Comment: @NowhereMan, так проще ответить, чем дубликат искать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сраниваете ссылки на экземпляры String,  true будет только если они указывают на один и тот же объект. Метод equals сравнивает символы в строках. Плюс можно было использовать

```
char symbol = scan.next().charAt(0);
            if (symbol == 'a')
```

тем самым сравнивая примитивные типы, а именно их числовое значение кодов.

Answer (score -1):

Значение строки нельзя проверить через оператор `==` для сравнения строк используйте метод `equals()`. Так же может быть полезен метод `contains()` который проверяет содержит ли одна строка другую.

заготовка:

```
String для проверки.contains(String который должен содержаться)
```

пример:

```
if ( "PrivetHelloZdravstvyite ".contains("Hello"))   //true
```